# how to store the count of search results from $find . -name "*.txt" in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I'm unable to store the count of search results from in unix so that i can use the variable in other expressions

```
$find . -name "*.txt"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$  find . -name “*.txt” | wc -l   # count the lines 

$  var=$(find <expr>|wc -l)
```

Comment: It might be a better idea to print a single known character for each file and then count characters, because your method will count files more than once if they have newlines in their names. Explicity: `find ... -printf "x" | wc -c`

Answer (score 0):

Another way not simply with gnu find.

```
nbfile=$(2>&1 find -D rates . -name "*.txt" 1>/dev/null | 
  sed -n '$s/.*\/\([^=]*\).*/\1/p')
echo "nbfiles = $nbfile"
```